# How can I mute an individual application from command line?

Tags: command-line, sound, google-chrome, mute

I can see a list of applications currently playing sound:

[image]

And I can mute them by clicking the On/Off slider.

How can I do thi from command line? I want to be able to mute `google-chrome`, so that I can answer my phone.

I can already play/pause spotify, but I can't use that technique for chrome, because Youtube doesn't integrate into the sound control system.